# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url)) while using the URL on requests module parsed by ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, configparser

I have an URL in the config file which I parsed using ConfigParser to get the requests

**config.ini**

```
[default]
root_url ='https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
```

FetchFeeds.py

```
import requests
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
import requests


config = ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../Config', 'config.ini'))
rootUrl = (config['default']['root_url'])
print(rootUrl)
response = requests.get(rootUrl)
```

Even the URL is printed properly `'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'`but I am getting the following error on the requests module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sam/PycharmProjects/testProject/GET_Request/FetchFeeds.py", line 11, in <module>
    response = requests.get(rootUrl)
  File "C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\testProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\testProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\testProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\testProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 637, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\testProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 730, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please note I checked carefully there are no white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is it tries to find a URL like `'url.com'` which doesn't exist (correct would be `url.com`), so the solution is to not put apostrophes in config.ini files:

```
[default]
root_url = https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
```

Also think about if you configure the parameters rather in your code than in the config file and use this instead:

```
requests.get(config['default']['root_url'], params={'page': 2})
```