# When accessing a Rest API via requests.get it times out. Same URL gets the response in browser

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to access a Rest API that supports GET, POST, PUT, MOVE functions. When I try the URL using the browser to get list of files I get a response from the REST API. However, when I try to call the same URL via requests.get(url) I get:

> (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D8CCFBC6A0>, 'Connection to  timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

What am I missing? Does it make any difference if I pass a JWT token within the URL?

URL in the browser returns a list in JSON.

```py
import requests
url = "https://www.restapi.com/content?JWT-token"
x = requests.get(url)
print(x.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the url within the browser it automatically finds the corresponding proxy for the url. I had to download the proxy file from browser's setting find the proxy mapping for that URL and add proxy parameters within the requests

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in Python, but it looks like you forgot quotes for link, it should look like this:

```py
url = 'https://wwww.restapi.com/content?JWT-token'
```

**EDIT:** Oh, you see, in your url you typed wwww instead of www. Is this ok?

Comment: Thank you but it shouldn't be 'url' otherwise you get a different error. Please see below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394684/

Comment: it is just a typo, it starts with www

Comment: Uhh.. whats wrong? That question is about config file, but You are in Python, your link must be a string, which is made by quotes

Comment: @TheEntropyShard OP probably does have quotes around their URL string, because they would be asking about a _different_ error if that was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this.

If you are in a corporate setup which uses proxy server for outbound connections, then you need to provide proxy details. The internet browser will already have the proxy configured.

```py
import os
#  Provide proxy details
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://user:password@proxy-server-ip:port"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://user:password@proxy-server-ip:port"

import requests
url = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users"
x = requests.get(url)
print(x.status_code)
print(x.content)
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem?